# How can I fix PlayonLinux and Python after upgrading Ubuntu Studio from 20.04 to 22.04?

Tags: python, 22.04, playonlinux

After upgrading, my panel shortcut broke and running playonlinux from command line gave the error that the package is not installed but can be apt get installed. (which I did). However, running playonlinux now returns the errors below, which I think are to do with Python.

I followed the instructions here
https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-python-3-10-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/
to install python 3.10, but still the errors.

Has the upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 broken my Python? What should I do to fix PlayonLinux?

I remember when installing Python there was a lot of steps I had to go through manually setting up static links to libraries. I wonder if the new version of Ubuntu overwrote these.

````
playonlinux
Looking for python3... 3.10.6 - Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1013,wx containers,compatible with 2.8),
and wxCore used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1016,wx containers,compatible with 2.8).
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: line 55: 37840 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Looking for python... 
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.18 - Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1013,wx containers,compatible with 2.8),
and wxCore used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1016,wx containers,compatible with 2.8).
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: line 55: 37853 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.18 - Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1013,wx containers,compatible with 2.8),
and wxCore used 3.0 (wchar_t,compiler with C++ ABI 1016,wx containers,compatible with 2.8).
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: line 55: 37865 Aborted                 (core dumped) "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program```
````

Comment: Ubuntu Studio 20.04 was the last release using the Xfce desktop, and had no upgrade path except via re-install. Did you read the release notes? https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-release-notes/ states "*Due to the change in desktop environment, direct upgrades to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS from versions prior to 21.10 are unsupported*" thus problems should have been expected.  Yes your Ubuntu base system will offer the upgrade; but the release notes & warnings posts from Ubuntu Studio said to re-install to avoid breakage.

Comment: Even Ubuntu upgrade docs warned you of breakage too - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JammyUpgrades via the upgrades from 20.04 excluded.

Comment: @guiverc, is Xfce actually implicated here? And I thought "supported" (or unsupported) in that text only meant that Canonical Ltd's customer services would (or wouldn't) support me - if I was ever inclined to contact them (which I'm not). I'd be grateful for anyone's practical advice.

Comment: Supported relates to the Ubuntu Studio & Ubuntu community; Ubuntu Studio (including Xfce or KDE) is a community supported entity; Ubuntu Desktop is what is supported by Canonical and that is GNOME only (though parts of GNOME tools are community supported too).  Canonical support 'main' packages only; where Xfce/KDE/Ubuntu-Studio are found in 'universe' or community supported. No support does not relate to Canonical as you weren't using a Canonical supported product; a Ubuntu (community) supported product where the upgrade you performed was *unsupported* by the team

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this for myself.

Although the error from PlayonLinux doesn't mention it, this is really an error with wxwidgets, which I had previously compiled from a tarball. My vague understanding is that software compiled from a tarball is tailored to the specific local PC, and so it makes sense to me that changing from 20.04 to 22.04 would mean this wxwidgets might need to be uninstalled and recompiled.

To uninstall the old wxwidgets, I had to go back into the "source" folder - i.e. the folder where I had unpacked its tarball several years ago - and run:-

$ sudo make uninstall

(other guides say run make uninstall but ubuntu I think does not use this "run" )

After this step, PlayonLinux began loading as normal again. But perhaps I will still want wxwidgets for something so I next downloaded the new tarball for wxwidgets version 3.2.1 from

https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.2.1/

and installed it using

$ sudo ./configure && make install

Comment: Well done for solving it, and thanks for sharing your solution.